# Cross Platform App Development Xamarin or React Native

Tags: cross-platform, mobile, react

I have to develop an app for Aphasia patients. I have hands-on experience of web development in PHP, Python and C# but never developed a mobile app. Can some experts recommend which platform is better Xamarin or React native considering the learning curve and also the features supported by both platforms? The app focuses on story writing and must support the following features:

```
Text-based story writing - users can choose a number of words from provided and also be able to rearrange or write new to write a story of their choice.

Image-Support - Users can create a story from images, upload images their own or use the recommended images.

A combination of both text and images to write the story

Move UI elements
```

I will highly appreciate any recommendations and suggestions in this regard.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending **software** – it's not about [comparisons](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) or asking for [languages](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185), [technologies](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185) etc.

Answer (score 1):

React Native community growing faster than Xamarin now. Both are good frameworks. Both have many ready made components. Now Xamarin compilation & development environment is little better than React Native,however Xamarin is not completely free for building enterprise apps.  I myself a python,php, .net,node.js & rust developer with good skills in JS so I prefer React Native and Native Script. As your skill are more towards C# you should go with Xamarin.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am trying my hands on Xamarin hopefully it would work for App. One more question does React native has good support for Image manipulation and UI features such as move, drag and drop of labels and text boxes?

Comment: Yes they have !